# Passing integration constants to self defined function

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to evaluate an integral I am taking in cylindrical coordinates, in which the integrand contains a previously defined function.  I need to pass the r and phi integrand values to this function so that it can be evaluated.  However I get the

> "integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling point errors"

when I do this.  If I simply pass numbers to my function call in the integrand, it works fine.  Here is the code, any help much appreciated!

Defined function:

```
SinsoidFluc[height_, factor_, scale_, x_, y_] := 
 Which[x > 2*Pi, SinsoidFluc[height, factor, scale, x - 2*Pi, y],
  x < -2*Pi, SinsoidFluc[height, factor, scale, x + 2*Pi, y],
  y > 2*Pi, SinsoidFluc[height, factor, scale, x, y - 2*Pi],
  y < -2*Pi, SinsoidFluc[height, factor, scale, x, y + 2*Pi], 
  x >= -2*Pi && x <= 2*Pi && y >= -2*Pi && y <= 2*Pi, 
  height - factor*Sin[x*scale]*Sin[y*scale]]
```

Would like to evaluate

```
PotentialCalc[height_, factor_, scale_, distance_] := 
 1/(4*Pi)*NIntegrate[
   SinsoidFluc[height, factor, scale, r*Cos[phi], r*Sin[phi]]*
    distance*r/(r^2 + distance^2)^1.5, {r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, 0, 
    2*Pi}]
```

If I change the integrand to another defined functions, I still get the error.

```
    Hole[x_, y_, radius_, holefraction_] := 
 Which[x^2 + y^2 <= radius, holefraction, x^2 + y^2 > radius, 1]
HolePotential[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ, radius_?NumberQ, 

  holefraction_?NumberQ, pitch_?NumberQ] := 
 Hole[x - Round[x, pitch], y - Round[y, pitch], radius, holefraction]

PotentialCalc[potential_, factor_, radius_, pitch_, distance_] := 
 1/(4*Pi)*NIntegrate[
   HolePotential[r*Cos[phi], r*Sin[phi], potential, radius, factor, 
     pitch]*distance*r/(r^2 + distance^2)^1.5, {r, 0, Infinity}, {phi,
     0, 2*Pi}]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. `PotentialCalc[2, 1, 1, 1]` returns `1.` without error.  BTW, do you know about `Mod[x, 2*Pi]`?  In particular `Sign[x] Mod[Abs[x], 2 Pi]` might replace the recursion in `SinsoidFluc` and speed up the computation.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I agree that passing hard values for x,y works.  What I want to do is to integrate over a spatially varying potential, I get the error when I replace 1,1 with r*Cos[phi],r*Sin[phi].  
Thanks for the recursion tip, I saw that on this forum to begin with, ill replace it as well.

Comment: Defining as `SinsoidFluc[height_?NumberQ,...]` will keep it effectively a black box function. So the minimization code will not attempt any symbolic processing that gives rise to such messages.

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean exactly?  If I want to pass the integrand parameters to the SinsoidFluc function, I would need to redefine the input parameters for that function as ?NumberQ   ?

Comment: Solution!  Changing the poor recursion to Michael's Sign/Mod product suggestion seems to have solved the issue.  Not sure why, but definitely a more elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: Changing the function in the integrand repeats the problem, I need to be able to input different functions in the integrand frequently.